# How get the content height of the UITextView with new line characters(\n)?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I need to calculate the height of the UItextview. But the text view having **new line**(\n) characters means, its not correctly calculate. 
Ex :

**Test** \n **Lorem Ipsum is simply** \n **dummy text of the printing** \n **and typesetting industry**

How to measure the UITextView content height with new line characters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use below code may be help you.

```
NSString *strtest =@"Test \n Lorem Ipsum is simply \n dummy text of the printing \n and typesetting industry";
yourtextView.text = strtest;
CGRect framefortext = _textView.frame;
framefortext.size.height = yourtextView.contentSize.height;
yourtextView.frame = framefortext;
```

Comment: Its not working for the "\n" characters in the text view. Is it working with newline text ?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to find and set the exact height of the label, Hope it helps to you too

```
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label sizeToFit];
int heightofbottom = label.frame.size.height;
NSLog(@"%d",heightofbottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentsSeparatedBy:` method and `sizeWithFont:` method of NSString.

get all you components sizes with sizeWithFont method, and then summarize all heights - it
will be result hight, and select biggest width - it will be result width.

f.e.

```
- (CGSize)sizeFromString:(NSString *)string {
    NSArray *componentsArray = [string componentsSeparatedBy:@"n\\"];
    CGFloat resultHeight = 0.f;
    CGFloat resultWidth = 0.f;
    for (NSString *component in componentsArray) {
        CGSize componentSize = [component sizeWithAttributes: ....]; // some attributes
        resultHeight += componentSize.height; 
        componentWidth = componentSize.width;
        if (componentWidth > resultWidth) {
            resultWidth = componentWidth
        }
    }
    return CGSizeMake(resultWidth, resultHeight);
}
```

maybe you should summarize also heights of "vertical paddings" (intervals between text lines)